# SSRS comparison of two datasets for "Difference Table"

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

We are rolling out new Symantec clients that connect to a new server. I've built a report that shows the rollout status.

So far so good. Now I try to report the servers, that are not visible in the new environment.

- Source 1: SEPM-Database on SQL Server A
- Source 2: SCCM-Database on SQL Server B

Datasets that querying the things that I need are already there.

Server name values of the fields are identical.

My goal is a table that compares:

- "SEPM-Database servernames" with "SCCM-Database servernames"

and writes only the server names into the table that **ARE NOT** in both.

Need this to check out which server hasn't joined the new environment.

Sorry, hope you understand what I mean. SSRS is very new to me. In the attached screenshot, you can see my first report that I have now:

**First report created**

[image]

**Visual overview database "relations"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as a full join like this.

```
WITH
sepm_server_list
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'SEPM', 'Server1')
    , ( 'SEPM', 'Server2')
    , ( 'SEPM', 'Server3')
    , ( 'SEPM', 'Server4')
    ) tbl ([DatabaseName], [ServerName]) 
)
, 
sccm_server_list
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'SCCM', 'Server1')
    , ( 'SCCM', 'Server2')
    , ( 'SCCM', 'Server3')
    , ( 'SCCM', 'Server5')
    ) tbl ([DatabaseName], [ServerName]) 
)
SELECT
      sepm.*
    , sccm.*
FROM 
    sepm_server_list AS sepm 
    FULL JOIN sccm_server_list AS sccm ON sepm.[ServerName] = sccm.[ServerName]
WHERE
    1=1
    AND 
        (
        sepm.[ServerName] IS NULL
        OR 
        sccm.[ServerName] IS NULL
        )
```

[image]

Or you could write it as an except statement with a union, to get the values in the same columns.

```
WITH
sepm_server_list
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'SEPM', 'Server1')
    , ( 'SEPM', 'Server2')
    , ( 'SEPM', 'Server3')
    , ( 'SEPM', 'Server4')
    ) tbl ([DatabaseName], [ServerName]) 
)
, 
sccm_server_list
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'SCCM', 'Server1')
    , ( 'SCCM', 'Server2')
    , ( 'SCCM', 'Server3')
    , ( 'SCCM', 'Server5')
    ) tbl ([DatabaseName], [ServerName]) 
)
SELECT DatabaseName = 'SEPM', A.[ServerName] FROM 
(
    SELECT [ServerName] FROM sepm_server_list
    EXCEPT
    SELECT [ServerName] FROM sccm_server_list
) A
UNION
SELECT DatabaseName = 'SCCM', B.[ServerName] FROM 
(
    SELECT [ServerName] FROM sccm_server_list
    EXCEPT
    SELECT [ServerName] FROM sepm_server_list
) B
```

[image]

Here's an example with the queries you posted.

```
WITH
sepm_server_list
AS
(
    SELECT [DatabaseName] = 'SEPM', [ServerName] = COMPUTER_NAME FROM v_sem_computer
)
, 
sccm_server_list
AS
(
    SELECT [DatabaseName] = 'SCCM', [ServerName] = F.[Name] FROM (v_Collection AS C LEFT JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership AS F ON F.CollectionID = C.CollectionID) WHERE C.[Name] = 'ALL_SERVERS_neu'
)
SELECT DatabaseName = 'SEPM', A.[ServerName] FROM 
(
    SELECT [ServerName] FROM sepm_server_list
    EXCEPT
    SELECT [ServerName] FROM sccm_server_list
) A
UNION
SELECT DatabaseName = 'SCCM', B.[ServerName] FROM 
(
    SELECT [ServerName] FROM sccm_server_list
    EXCEPT
    SELECT [ServerName] FROM sepm_server_list
) B
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not totally clear till yet....

For example, I'm quering SEPM Database like this:
select COMPUTER_NAME from v_sem_computer

Then the SCCM Database:
select F.Name AS Computername, C.CollectionID, C.Name AS CollectionName
FROM (v_Collection AS C
  LEFT JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership AS F ON F.CollectionID = C.CollectionID)
  where C.Name = 'ALL_SERVERS_neu'
  Order By F.Name

But I don't understand how to use this two queries in your example query. Can you explain it to me?

Thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: If you change out the first 2 table expressions with your queries and alias the "COMPUTER_NAME" as ServerName it should work for you.

Comment: Hello Tony, first of all: Thank you soo much for all of your effort!
I've update my question to show you, how the "relation" is.
You can see, the first "Select" is OK (It's clear, because I've selected the "sem5" database for the query. But the second tables are not known at the moment. To reach my goal, i have to "join" the second database "CM_PDU" to the query. For that, I need a little help again. 

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the query returning results? Are there results missing from one or both sides?